# Is there a way to run n command lines at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function which runs a long process and writes to a file.

To make things faster, I was opening *n* python consoles, and executing that function in each.

My question: is there is a way to do this in a single instance of the python console.

Here's the source I'm working through:

```
def test_random():
    while True:
        kwargs = random_aco_args()
        args = ()
        num_cities = kwargs.pop("num_cities")
        tsp_model = get_model(num_cities)
        print_test(num_cities, kwargs)
        run_aco(tsp_model, *args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_random()
```

and here is the script I created to call it with Popen:

```
from subprocess import Popen

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f_path = "C:\\Users\\Y\\Desktop\\sketches\\Search_algorithms\\tsp\\testtd.py"
    for _ in range(0,20):
        Popen([sys.executable, f_path])
```

Comment: You can use `Popen` and not wait for results.

Comment: Use https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen with shell=True

Comment: If they don't have to be running simultaneously, you can use a Python script!

Comment: @I.Renk Python has a very good multi-threading and multi-process library.  However, I do think subprocess.Popen would be the correct function to use (to avoid reinventing the wheel with whatever command you are using).

Comment: @AmitTripathi `shell=True` is dangerous, he can just use `Popen` without waiting for the output, no shell required.

Comment: @DylanLawrence i updated the question with the code I want to run, and the script i made to run it, using Popen. I am getting an error thoug, "not a valid windows application"

Comment: @RafaelMarques You need to do `Popen(['python',f_path])` windows doesn't know how to run a `.py` file.

Comment: yeah, that was it, thank you all!
@DylanLawrence